# SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL Pyramid update issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have the following model:

```
class Employee (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name     = Column(String(300), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone_a  = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    phone_b  = Column(String(20))
    email_a  = Column(String(400), nullable=False)
    email_b  = Column(String(400))
    address  = Column(String)
    charge   = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    active   = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    created  = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    modified = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __init__(self):
        self.active  = True
        self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I wrote the add view for it, very basic:

```
employee = Employee()
form     = Form(request, EmployeeSchema(), obj = employee)

if form.validate():
    employee = form.bind(Employee())
    try:
        DBSession.add(employee)
        DBSession.flush()
        return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('employees'))
    except IntegrityError:
        message = 'Oops!'
```

And it works well. But the UPDATE view doesn't. I just does not save. According to the tutorial basically with the same code it should work. But it doesn't, SQLAlchemy tries to insert a new object instead of just updating it. I tried

```
import transaction
transaction.commit()
```

But no success.

```
_id = request.matchdict['employeeid']
employee = DBSession.query(Employee).filter_by(id=_id).first()
form     = Form(request, EmployeeSchema(), obj = employee)

if form.validate():
    employee    = form.bind(Employee())
    try:
        DBSession.add(employee)
        return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('employees'))
    except IntegrityError:
        message = ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind to the item, you do *not* need to add a new `Employee()` instance:

```
_id = request.matchdict['employeeid']
employee = DBSession.query(Employee).get(_id)
form     = Form(request, EmployeeSchema(), obj=employee)

if form.validate():
    form.bind(employee)
    return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('employees'))
```

That's it.

Comment: Shouldn't you commit the session after the bind?

Comment: The session is automatically committed by the pyramid transaction middleware.

Comment: K. In that case, why do you need to add to the session? Isn't it already in the session using the query? Or is this another Pyramid thing?

Comment: It's been a while; replaced with a merge.

Comment: I don't think you even need the merge: the employee will already be in the session because you queried it.

Comment: @JosueMontano: You bind to the *existing* `employee` object, so that the `form` object can update its attributes.

Comment: @MarkHildreth: Indeed; I had to go back to [the session use docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#adding-new-or-existing-items) because it differs from source to source what they are using; `.merge()` or `.add()`. Both are no-ops for the `employee` object.

Comment: For everyone following this without success: Be sure to have `pyramid_tm` in your `pyramid.includes` (in your ini-file). Otherwise there will be no middleware to automatically commit. I started my project with a scaffold without DB, and it took me some time to find that problem.